# Something wrong in BINDING in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two select. If you chose an item in the first, automatically the second one fills with the subarray. It works. But I want to add new field, same field but isolated. Now, if I add new fields, the others selection change. I want to prevent this. How can I do? Thank you! [CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/AkdZ4U3CGRWKXxUCenqx?p=preview)

```
<div data-ng-repeat="food in foods track by $index">
   <select ng-model="select1" ng-options="a.id as a.nome for a in list.products" ng-change="selectLot(select1)">
    <option value="">-- Select Product --</option>
   </select>

<select ng-model="select2" ng-options="a.id as a.value for a in Subarray" ng-if="Subarray" ng-change="lotSelect(select2)">
  <option value="">-- Select Lot --</option>
</select>
</div>
<button ng-click="newLine();">Add Line</button> 
<button ng-click="removeLine();" class="{{$index}}">Remove</button>

<h1>INFO ABOUT SELECTION</h1>
{{allInfo}}
```

P.S. also *{{allInfo}}* doesn't work and I don't know why... (it should contains the info, like [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/NNAcdFU7ZG24ido83BtA?p=preview)

Comment: It is the second select. It is enabled if you choose something in the first one. Becuse select2 contains the subarray of the selected item

Comment: but you are not sending this "selected item" to the second selection

Comment: The first 2 items contains empty sub-array. Try to press the last. The second <select> just show the sub-array of the json selected element

Comment: i posted an answer let me know if this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this: 
as you can see, I send the selectedProduct to the second selection.

```
<select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="a as a.nome for a in list.products">


<select ng-model="selectedLot" ng-options="a as a.id for a in selectedProduct.lots" ng-if="selectedProduct.lots">
```

You won't need to change anything in the controller.

Comment: Perfect it works very nice, thank you! The last thing, how can I display the {{allInfo}} array, containing the info?

Comment: your allInfo is selectedProduct and selectedLot , you can add an ng-change to each select and update {{allInfo}}